# Windows 10 startup-sound

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, system-sounds

Is there a way to get the startup sound back in Windows 10?
If there is a way to enable it, can you change it to your own sound? Or can you change the logon-sound to one if the other things don't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Control Panel/Sounds, in the tab Sounds, there is a check box 'Play Windows Startup Sound'. Just check it.

Comment: It's so simple? Uh, sorry about asking a so stupid question.

Comment: SE allowed me after 10 mins ;-)